# Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer'

Tags: video.js

We are using VideoJs (6.9.0) to create and HTML5 Web App to be used on SmartTVs. We are noticing that some of the TVs are reporting the following error:

**Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': The SourceBuffer is full and cannot free space to append additional buffers.**

We are using the VideoJS HLS and Google IMA Plugins. This does not happen in a computer web browser. Just on certain models of SmartTVs. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by following what was done here:
https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/pull/1416

Comment: Question: Are you using hls.js and did you apply fixes to that library to fix this?